# mongo db docker image authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo mongo image in my local docker environment, but I'm getting `Authentication failed` error. In `docker-compose` I add it like:

```
 my-mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name:  my-mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdfasdf
    networks:
      - mynet
```

I also tried to run mongo CLI from inside the container but still getting the same error:

```
root@76e6db78228b:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("c87c0f0e-fe83-41a6-96e9-4aa4ede8fa25") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.3
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
> use translations
switched to db translations  
> db.auth("mongo", "asdfasdf")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

Also, I'm trying to create a separate user:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
db.auth("mongo", "asdfasdf")
1
> db.createUser({
    user: "user",
    pwd: "asdfasdf",
    roles: [  {role: "readWrite", db: "translations" }  ]
    })
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "user",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "translations"
                }
        ]
}
> use translations
switched to db translations  
> db.auth("user", "asdfasdf")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

and the same, what I'm doing wrong???

**Updated:**

```
root@8bf81ef1fc4f:/# mongo -u mongo -p asdfasdf --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("02231489-eaf4-40be-a108-248cec88257e") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.3
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-02-26T16:24:12.942+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-02-26T16:24:12.943+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-02-26T16:24:12.943+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

> db.createUser({user: "someuser", pwd: "asdfasdf", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "translations"}]})
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "someuser",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "translations"
                }
        ]
}
> use translations
switched to db translations
> db.auth("someuser", "asdfasdf")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

as stated in the [Docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that
>   user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication
>   database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

so you need to add `--authenticationDatabase admin` to your command since the mongod will be started with `mongod --auth`

example:

```
mongo -u mongo -p asdfasdf --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: still can't add new user. See CLI outpur in updates for original question

Comment: I want to add non-admin user add permissions for that user to the database I need

Comment: actually you are right I should but I need switch to the database I need before adding user. Not sure why I need to do it as I still setting database in the use roles

Answer (score 25):

After some time, I figured out.

- On the same folder, create `docker-compose.yml` and `init-mongo.js`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name : your-cont-name
    command: mongod --auth
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
    volumes: 
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      
volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
```

**init-mongo.js**

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "your_user",
        pwd: "your_password",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "my_db"
            }
        ]
    }
);
db.createCollection("test"); //MongoDB creates the database when you first store data in that database
```

**Auth**

*First, execute the bash inside the container*

```
docker exec -it your-cont-name bash
```

Now we can login.
For the *admin*

```
mongo -u admin -p root
```

For the *your_user* you have **to specify the db (with the --authenticationDatabase)** otherwise you'll have an auth error

```
mongo -u your_user -p your_password --authenticationDatabase my_db
```

After that, you should switch to the right db with

```
use my_db
```

If you don't execute this command, you'll be on *test* db

**Note**

For being sure of having the right config, i prefer to

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm
docker volume rm <your-volume>
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: So you if you don't create a user with db.createUser()  in the entrypoint ( - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro ) you can't login as the root user defined in the env variables ( MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_db, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin , MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root ) ? So what are these environment variables for ? do they not create an user with a password for that initdb ? Another question, how do you hide your password from git, you have it inside this .js file ?

Comment: This worked like a charm to me, but you really don't need to change the command

Answer (score 19):

i have the same issue, after google two hours finally sovled;
solution：find out the host machine direcory mounted into mongodb container, delete it,then re-create the mongodb container.

mongo db container create by docker-compose.yaml mount a diretory from host mechine to the container for save the mongo datbases. when you remove the container the mouted direcotry do not deleted, so the default username and password pass by env var could be long time ago you set, now you change the user name and password. just do not work,cause recreate the container will not recreate the "admin" database .

Comment: That really helped. Could have never thought this.

Comment: Thanks that was my problem

Comment: I was struggling for days, then I read this answer and then I realized the issue. My problem was more subtle: I changed laptop and, being lazy, I just copy-pasted the whole folder. The old volume was a hidden sub-folder, but the docker-compose.yaml still used it, and the authentication failed. After removing it, it worked like a charm!

Comment: great. it works on k8s either. I removed the pvc assigned to pod that installed at my first time. then reinstall it. solve the problem!

Answer (score 6):

I've fallen in this trap and wasted a day while everything was correct.

I'm writing this for future me(s) because it wasn't mentioned anywhere else and also to avoid my mistake while setting up user/pass combination to connect to their database from other services.

### Assuming everything is right:

If you are mounting some local folder of yours as storage for your database like below:

```yaml
services:
  your_mongo_db:
    // ...some config

    volumes:
      - ./__TEST_DB_DATA__:/data/db
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    environment:
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root"
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass"

    //...more config
```

**Please remember to remove this folder before re-running your compose file.** I think when you run the `docker-compose` command for the first time, Mongo will create and store the user data there (like any other collections) and then reuse it for the next time (since you mounted that volume).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem myself,

Please first remove the username and password from credentials.

```
environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongo
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdfasdf
```

after you remove the credentials you may check dbs or users on your mongodb.

```
show dbs
show users
```

Those commands also needs auth, so if you can see them, can be null, then you fix your issue.

Than,
then create a admin user,

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "root", roles:["root"]})
```

then you can logout and try to connect with credentials to the shell as an admin.

In addition if you are still having some issues about creating new user,
In my case I changed mechanisms to SCRAM-SHA-1 than it worked like a charm.

```
{
  user: "<name>",
  pwd: passwordPrompt(),      // Or  "<cleartext password>"
  customData: { <any information> },
  roles: [
    { role: "<role>", db: "<database>" } | "<role>",
    ...
  ],
  authenticationRestrictions: [
     {
       clientSource: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...],
       serverAddress: ["<IP>" | "<CIDR range>", ...]
     },
     ...
  ],
  mechanisms: [ "<SCRAM-SHA-1|SCRAM-SHA-256>", ... ],
  passwordDigestor: "<server|client>"
}
```

Comment: So you if you don't create a user with db.createUser() in the entrypoint ( - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro ) you can't login as the root user defined in the env variables ( MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_db, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin , MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root ) ? So what are these environment variables for ? do they not create an user with a password for that initdb ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem myself, follows this steps:
Steps 1 and 2 are to delete de old configuration, and set and apply the new configuration, its so important:

1. Delete to the containers **mongo**:
   `docker rm mongo -f`
2. If you have created volumes, delete them:
   `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q) -f`
3. In ***ports*** field of docker-compose.yml set:
   **- 27018:27017** ->
   Its so important that ports is not *27017:27017*, in my case it was generating conflict.
4. Up docker compose:
   `docker-compose up`
5. Try now the connection with authentication!

Example of docker-compose.yml:

```
mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Madrid"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "user"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "admin1"
    volumes:
      - ./mongoDataBase:/data/db        
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
```

Best regards!

Comment: I couldn't find out what is the problem but as you mentioned deleting mongo container and volume helps :)

Comment: Deleting the container and volume helped me too!

Answer (score 1):

the error maybe related with docker volumes, try to remove old ones and create a new volume in docker-compose.yaml. I think it's related with initial scripts that set your username and pass to static files, so you need recreate that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).