# MongoDb authentication failing on accessing database while using docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to setup password to mongodb

My docker-compose file is

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
            - MONG_INITDB_DATABASE=example
```

Now after running the docker container, when I try
**after going inside the container**

```
mongo mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017
```

It connects successfully,

but when I try

```
mongo mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/example
```

authentication fails.
MongoDB shell version v4.2.7
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/example?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-06-16T17:51:08.226+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17

Comment: You seem to be running another mongod process on the host system, use port 27016 for the container one.

Comment: When I am accessing inside container its still running on default 27017, outside when I am accessing in node app, I am using docker-compose, so DNS map mongo to containers IP, hence still 27017. I mapped it outside to 27016 as I had a local instance running on 27017

Comment: For anyone having problem, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702253/5723524

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not sure why it was not mentioned in any blog or tutorial but according to official docs,
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#components

```
/defaultauthdb  
Optional. The authentication database to use if the connection string includes username:password@ authentication credentials but the authSource option is unspecified.

If both authSource and defaultauthdb are unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the specified user to the admin database.
```

So what finally worked was adding authSource, without authSource mongod tries to find the creds in /example db thus giving error, after adding authSource

```
mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/example?authSource=admin
```

This worked and successfully added data to example db

Comment: Holy WOW!  I was trying everything and authSource=admin fixed it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should try connecting to `mongodb://root:password@localhost:27016/example` from outside the container as you mapped the 27017 port of your docker container to your host's 27016 port.

Comment: Same it connects when
mongo mongodb://root:password@localhost:27016
but fails when
mongo mongodb://root:password@localhost:27016/example

Comment: Not sure but https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#components states that /defaultdb is the database where auth details are checked, so when I tried appending /admin it worked but I want to specify new db

Comment: Yeah! if you want to connect with example, you should define `MONGODB_DATABASE=example` in your docker-compose environment variables

Comment: mongo mongodb://root:password@localhost:27016/example?authSource=admin
This also works

Comment: The connection string would be this: `mongodb://root:password@localhost:27016/example?authSource=example` if you set that env variable

Comment: MONG_INITDB_DATABASE was variable mentioned on website, which I have already set as example in my docker-compose

Comment: Yeah, the variable I mentioned is for the bitnami image, though the concept is the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. "MONG_INITDB_DATABASE" will not create DB unless it's there in your data volume binding i.e "./data:/data/db". If it's there then you need to use the specific roles which were used to create under "data"
2. If it's not #1 then you need to provide a file which will create the database under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js`. Below is an template:

   ```
   db.createUser(
       {
           user: "<user for database which shall be created>",
           pwd: "<password of user>",
           roles: [
               {
                   role: "readWrite",
                   db: "<database to create>"
               }
           ]
       }
   );
   ```

You can refer more at their official [docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). Section: **MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE** and **Initializing a fresh instance**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and deleting docker volumes solved it. They have been saved with different credentials and I changed it in the meantime, so it was conflicting, therefore it failed my authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add (for anyone else facing this issue) that I took the following steps:

1. Deleted the mongo image
2. Deleted the associated container(s)
3. Deleted the associated volumes.
4. Pulled the mongo image again

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).